# Can't add a STORED column to MariaDB 10.7.3, Infamous "Error Code 1901"

Tags: date, mariadb, calculated-columns

I'm trying to add a GENERATED ALWAYS column to a table that will decode two characters into a `DATE`.

It contains a function (returning `DATE`), but it was misbehaving the same way when the expression was in-lined. The function works fine in a SELECT. I've checked my character set and collation for consistency.

sql_mode is "ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

Here is the table schema. Note I have a `Location` generated column, which is working fine.

```
CREATE TABLE `Photo_Gear_Date_Codes` (
  `ID` varchar(4) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL DEFAULT '....',
  `Location` varchar(253) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (case left(`ID`,2) when 'TN' then 'Tatsuno, Hyogo' else 'Unknown' end) STORED,
  `Note` varchar(1022) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

Here is the function I defined to try to simplify things, although I got the same error when I in-lined this code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1`
FUNCTION `Date_from_OM_date_code`(id3 char(1), id4 char(1))
RETURNS date
DETERMINISTIC
COMMENT 'Decode the last two digits of a four-character OM date code.'
RETURN CONVERT(
    concat(
      case ID3
        when '1' then '1971'
        when '2' then '1972'
        when '3' then '1973'
        when '4' then '1974'
        when '5' then '1975'
        when '6' then '1976'
        when '7' then '1977'
        when '8' then '1978'
        when '9' then '1979'
        when '0' then '1980'
        when 'A' then '1981'
        when 'B' then '1982'
        when 'C' then '1983'
        when 'D' then '1984'
        when 'E' then '1985'
        when 'F' then '1986'
        when 'G' then '1987'
        when 'H' then '1988'
        when 'I' then '1989'
        when 'J' then '1990'
        when 'K' then '1991'
        when 'L' then '1992'
        when 'M' then '1993'
        when 'N' then '1994'
        when 'O' then '1995'
        when 'P' then '1996'
        when 'Q' then '1997'
        when 'R' then '1998'
        when 'S' then '1999'
        when 'T' then '2000'
        when 'U' then '2001'
        when 'V' then '2002'
        when 'W' then '2003'
        when 'X' then '2004'
        when 'Y' then '2005'
        when 'Z' then '2006'
        end,
      case ID4
        when '1' then '-01-00'
        when '2' then '-02-00'
        when '3' then '-03-00'
        when '4' then '-04-00'
        when '5' then '-05-00'
        when '6' then '-06-00'
        when '7' then '-07-00'
        when '8' then '-08-00'
        when '9' then '-09-00'
        when 'A' then '-10-00'
        when 'B' then '-11-00'
        when 'C' then '-12-00'
        when 'X' then '-10-00'
        when 'Y' then '-11-00'
        when 'Z' then '-12-00'
        end), DATE);
```

Here is how I'm trying to add the generated column:

```
USE `Personal`;
ALTER TABLE `Photo_Gear_Date_Codes` ADD COLUMN `Date` DATE AS 
  (Date_from_OM_date_code(SUBSTR(`ID`,3,1), RIGHT(`ID`,1))) STORED;
SELECT ID,
  `Location`,
  Date_from_OM_date_code(SUBSTR(`ID`,3,1), RIGHT(`ID`,1)) `Date`
  FROM Photo_Gear_Date_Codes
```

When I execute those three statements, the second throws the 1901 error code:

> Function or expression '`Date_from_OM_date_code`()' cannot be used in
> the GENERATED ALWAYS AS clause of `Date`
>
> Error code 1901.

But I proceed through the error, and the `SELECT` works just fine!

| ID | Location | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S7Y | Unknown | 1977-11-00 |
| TND1 | Tatsuno, Hyogo | 1984-01-00 |
| TND4 | Tatsuno, Hyogo | 1984-04-00 |
| TNGB | Tatsuno, Hyogo | 1987-11-00 |
| TNH9 | Tatsuno, Hyogo | 1988-09-00 |
| TNI5 | Tatsuno, Hyogo | 1989-05-00 |
| TNJ2 | Tatsuno, Hyogo | 1990-02-00 |
| TNJ3 | Tatsuno, Hyogo | 1990-03-00 |
| TNJ5 | Tatsuno, Hyogo | 1990-05-00 |
| TNM6 | Tatsuno, Hyogo | 1993-06-00 |
| TNM9 | Tatsuno, Hyogo | 1993-09-00 |
| TNOA | Tatsuno, Hyogo | 1995-10-00 |

It seems like it should work… I'm pulling my hair out over this one!

Thanks in advance for pointing out where I'm being stupid! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mariadb's documentation on [generated column](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/) says:

> This expression might generate the value based on the values of other columns in the table, or it might generate the value by **calling built-in functions or user-defined functions (UDFs).**

UDFs are functions written in c++, not in sql. As you can see, standard, sql-based user created functions are not included in the list, hence the error message.

Include your function's body as an expression as the generated column's code instead.

Comment: Thank you! I could swear I had already tried that, and then moved everything to a function to try to figure things out, but I must have had some other error in the expression before moving it to a function. It's really too bad they don't allow deterministic functions in generated columns — that would be good for abstraction and re-use!

Comment: UDF are written in c++? how can that be, they _are_ written in sql! You mean the reverse, Build-in functions are written in c++!

Comment: @theking2 please click on the link in my answer, find the link on that page that leads to the definition of UDF in mariadb and you will see those are written in c/c++.

Comment: @Shadow apart from the fact that UDF cannot physically be transpiled in C++ as they are written in SQL I don't see where in the link you proposed it shows otherwise as there is no mention of c++ as far as Ctrl+f tells. It would mean compiling Mariadb Sources and restart the server

Comment: @theking2 in the linked page above you should have looked for the definition of UDFs, which has the link to the corresponding page in mariadb documentation: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-defined-functions/

Comment: @theking2 or you could just simply do a mariadb udf c++ Internet search and check out the results. Would have been a lot faster for you...

Comment: Interesting. I come from an original MS-SQL server environment and the result of CREATE FUNCTION is called a [user defined function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: @theking2 well, you need to get used to the mariadb concepts